# Inserting at the very end in FCKeditor

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, fckeditor

FCKeditor has InsertHtml API ([JavaScript API document](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API)) that inserts HTML in the current cursor position. How do I insert at the very end of the document?

Do I need to start browser sniffing with something like this

```
if ( element.insertAdjacentHTML )    // IE 
    element.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin',  html ) ; 
else                                // Gecko 
{ 
    var oRange = document.createRange() ; 
    oRange.setStartBefore( element ) ; 
    var oFragment = oRange.createContextualFragment( html ); 
    element.parentNode.insertBefore( oFragment,  element ) ; 
}
```

or is there a blessed way that I missed?

Edit: Of course, I can rewrite the whole HTML, as answers suggest, but I cannot believe that is the "blessed" way. That means that the browser should destroy whatever it has and re-parse the document from scratch. That cannot be good. For example, I expect that to break the undo stack.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use a combination of GetHTML and SetHTML to get the current contents, append your html and reinsert everything into the editor. Although it does say

> Note that when using this method, you will lose any listener that you may have previously registered on the editor.EditorDocument.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('Editor_instance') ;
    OldText=oEditor.GetXHTML( true );

    oEditor.SetData( OldText+"Your text");
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the buggy line `:element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', html);`

with this jquery code:

```
try {
      $(html).insertBefore($(element));
      // element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', html);

} catch (err) { }
```